# Add one2many field to a website form odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a web form it contains many input fields. I want to add an one2many field to it so that the user can select multiple lines and save them to DB. I want some like the one in this pic [image]

here is my code for the form :

```
<template id="create_operation" name="Create Operation">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="oe_structure">
                <div class="container">
                    <form role="form" action="/create/weboperation" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" t-att-value="name" id="name"
                                   class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email_id" t-att-value="email_id" id="email_id"
                                   class="form-control" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="picking_type_id" class="control-label">Operation Type</label>
                            <select name="picking_type_id" class="form-control link-style">
                                <t t-foreach='picking_rec' t-as="picking">
                                    <option t-esc='picking.name' t-att-value='picking.id'/>
                                </t>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix oe_login_buttons">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Create Patient</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you want to create new records in an existing model (res.partner, product.tempalte, sale...) or do you want to create your own independant model with its own fields ?

Comment: I want to create a record in an existing model

Comment: what I want is the same form view of operations transfer in the inventory module, I want to create a website form to do the same operation.

Comment: Please provide : 1) a screen capture of this form 2) the corresponding view template 3) the corresponding controller (file : inventory / controllers / main.py...)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create your custom one2many field on the right model : an existing one : product.template ? or a new one : my_model....

If you want to make it available in a webform (frontend template), you can t just use it as one2many field (not the same way as in backend templates), you must use html input fields :

```xml
<table>
  <thead><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>name</th>picking type</thead>
      <tbody>
      <t t-foreach=”[1,2,3]” t-as=”i”>
       <tr>

       <td><input type="text" t-att-value="" t-att-id="'name-'+str(i)" t-att-name="'name-'+str(i)" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" t-att-value="" t-att-id="'email-'+str(i)" t-att-name="'email-'+str(i)" /></td>
       <td><select t-att-id="'picking_type_id-'+str(i)" t-att-name="'picking_type_id-'+str(i)"><option>...</option></select></td>
        
        </tr>
       </t>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you should create your custom controller file (/your_module/controllers/main.py), for instance :

```py
       # A brand new one only for your model and its fields
       class MyOwnModelController(http.Controller):
       
       # A one inheriting the controller of an existing model
       class MyWebsiteSale(WebsiteSale):
```

And then create the "route" and the "def" corresponding to your form action (/create/weboperation) in this main.py file :

```py
       @http.route(["/create/weboperation"], type="http", methods=["GET", "POST"], auth="public", website=True, sitemap=False)
       def create_webop(self, qcontext):
          values['picking_type_id'] = qcontext.get('picking_type_id')
          #update : if your record is already existing in your model:
          your_record_id = qcontext.get('form_input_recordid')
          your_model_record = 
          self.env['your_model_name'].browse(your_record_id)
          your_model_record.write(values)
          # OR create : if you want to create a new record in your model:
          my_new_record = self.env['your_model_name'].create(values)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to use your code it gives me this error in the form with a red hint " Element [div,table,tbody,select, is not closed

Comment: after I pasted it inside the template

Comment: yes, i have corrected the missing end tag of <select>